# Properties of expectation values

Tags: statistics, expectation

I have a complicated problem in which I have to compute the expectation in order to see if my
estimator is unbiased or not. 
After a lot of calcutions at the end I have found:
$$
E[(\sqrt{A-c})(\sqrt{A+c})] 
$$where A is an expression which contains the random variable and c in a constant.

The exact expression for A and c are the following: 
$$
A=w(\sum_{i=1}^{g}y_{i}d_{i}-\beta_{0}\sum_{i}^{g}d_{i}))
$$
and 
$$
c=g\beta_{0}
$$
where the random variables are $y_{i}$ i.i.d with normal distribution N($\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}d_i$, $\sigma^{2}$) .
And this calculation is to prove that $\beta_1$ is unbiased.

I have tryed in a lot of way but I don't really get which trick I should use.. 
I hope that someone could help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The operator $E$ is linear and one can exploit its properties when the inner term is linear too (or at least is the sum of some terms). In this case, since there is the square root, few thing can be said unless you specify the probability density function of the random variable itself.

Comment: Would Jensen's inequality be of use (if $X$ is a random variable and $\varphi$ is a concave function, then $\operatorname E\varphi(X)\le\varphi(\operatorname E X)$)?

Comment: I don't think so because this is the calculation for proving that the estimator is unbiased, so I should get equility by the direct calculation of it. However now I will edit my question by adding the exact expression for A and c .